# jQuery animate .prepend

Tags: jquery

Rather than simply dumping the HTML into the page I want it to be animated, how can I change the jQuery below to either animate or slide down as the HTML is inserted?

```
$('.button').click(function() {

j('.tweets ul').prepend(j('.refreshMe ul').html());

});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) the content before doing a [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/), then call [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) on the element, like this:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
 j('.refreshMe ul > *').clone().hide().prependTo('.tweets ul').slideDown();
});
```

This does [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) of the children to move, rather than doing an innerHTML style copy, hides the cloned elements before moving them, then slides them down.