# Possible to animate jQuery prepend?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, prepend

I am prepending some data to my page on a button click and instead of just populating immediately on the page, I was wondering if there is a way to animate the `prepend()` using `slideToggle` or CSS animation.

Here is my current script:

```
var data = $('.data').html();
var insert = '<div class="data-container">'+ data +'</div>';
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.data-container').remove();
    $('.initial').prepend(insert);
});
```

and a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ad8UG/)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520178/

Comment: you mean this:http://jsfiddle.net/TD784/

Comment: Perfect @EhsanSajjad, if you want to turn that into an answer, I will gladly accept it when I am able to. Thanks!

Comment: @APAD1 added as answer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do something like this:

```
var data = $('.data').html();
var insert = '<div class="data-container">'+ data +'</div>';
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.data-container').remove();
    $('.initial').hide();
    $('.initial').prepend(insert);
    $('.initial').slideToggle();

});
```

[**FIDDLE UPDATED**](http://jsfiddle.net/TD784/)

Answer (score 21):

This one liner works great for me, even without the `clone()`

I'm using it like so:

```
var elementToPrepend = "<div>Your content</div>";
$(elementToPrepend).hide().prependTo(".prependHere").fadeIn();
```

Edit: Proper one-liner would be:

```
$("<div>Your content</div>").hide().prependTo(".prependHere").fadeIn();
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3579393/3484824)

Answer (score 4):

You can animate `prepend()` or `append()` quite easy. Just pass the whole animated object as a parameter, like so:

```
$("#container").prepend( $(data).hide().delay(500).show('slow') );
```

If you like it more readable:

```
var object = $(data).hide().delay(500).show('slow');
$("#container").prepend(object);
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/zR9fN/5/

**CSS**

```
/* add display:none; to keep it hidden after being prepended */
.data-container {
    display:none;
    ...
}
```

**jQuery**

```
....
$('.initial').prepend(insert);
$('.data-container').fadeIn('slow'); // fade in the prepended content that was hidden
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = $('.data').html();
var insert = '<div id="animationWrapper" style="height: 0"><div class="data-container">'+ data +'</div></div>';
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.data-container').remove();
    $('.initial').prepend(insert);
    jQuery('#animationWrapper').animate({height: '300px'}, 5000, function(){console.log('Yammie!')})
});
```

Please check the syntax, but this should be a start.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply animate **before prepending**.
If you animate it before prepending it will appear with animation.

for example

```
childContainer.fadeIn(1000);
$(containerElement).prepend(childContainer);
```

Alternative to **fadeIn** you can use any animation.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do in two lines to get a smooth slideDown animation:

```
$("<div>Your content</div>").hide().prependTo(".prependHere");
$(".prependHere:first-child").slideDown();
```