# How to prevent other elements not to change position when some specific element prepend?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem that when I prepend div by pressing input button it(button) also goes down with div which I added very first time.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $("#addBut").click(function() {


    $('body').prepend('<div class="content"  id="first' + count + '"><h3>Heading tag</h3><p>Paragraph tag</p></div>');
    //It is the jquery code div which I prepends
    count++;

  });

  $("#TextBut")
    .click(function() {
      var value = $(inpText).val();
      $("#para").text(value);
    })
});
```

```css
#addBut {
  //style of button which goes down
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
}
.content {
  //style of div which is to be prepend
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  padding: 25px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="inpText">
  <textarea rows="12" cols="50">//it is text area which also goes down TextArea Location
  </textarea>
  <input type="button" id="addBut" value="Add">// HTML tag of Button which goes down
  <input type="button" id="TextBut">
</div>
```

Can any one please help me that how to avoid other contents not to change their position when some specific element is prepend?

Comment: Did you tried append?

Comment: Sory, I used prepend.

Comment: May be it does not happen with append.

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=0;
$("#addBut").click(function(){

$('body').append('<div style="font-size:200%;border:1px solid black;margin-bottom:5px;"  id="first'+count+'">div '+count+'</div>');
    count++;
});
$("#delBut").click(function(){
$("#first5").remove();
});
});
</script>

Comment: Use above JQUERY code with prepend to check the exact location of div. I want new div to be added at the top of the body

Answer (score 0):

Prepend inserts new element Before the others, and Append inserts element After, so you need to use Append instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/9k1nf6za/

```
$('body').append('<div class="content"  id="first'+count+'"><h3>Heading tag</h3><p>Paragraph tag</p></div>');
```

Comment: But I need new DIV at the top of the page when it is added

Comment: Everything is possible to be done, but please say how do you want to insert a new element, before the other elements without moving them, to make space for it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the bellow code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>prepend demo</title>
<style>
#addBut{     //style of button which goes down
display: block; padding: 3px 10px; cursor: pointer; margin: auto;
}

.content{       //style of div which is to be prepend
position:relative;
background-color: white;
width: 500px;
height:350px;
padding: 25px;
border: 5px solid black;
 display:block;
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
top:200px; 
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input type="text" id="inpText"> 
<textarea rows="12" cols="50">   //it is text area which also goes down
TextArea Location    
</textarea>
<input type="button" id="addBut" value="Add"> // HTML tag of Button which goes down
<input type="button" id="TextBut">
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=0;
$("#addBut").click(function(){


$('body').append('<div class="content"  id="first'+count+'"><h3>Heading tag</h3><p>Paragraph tag</p></div>'); 
//It is the jquery code div which I prepends
count++;

});

$( "#TextBut" )
.click(function() {
var value = $( inpText ).val();
$( "#para" ).text( value );
})
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But I need new DIV at the top of the page when it is added

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=0;
$("#addBut").click(function(){

$('body').append('<div style="font-size:200%;border:1px solid black;margin-bottom:5px;"  id="first'+count+'">div '+count+'</div>');
    count++;
});
$("#delBut").click(function(){
$("#first5").remove();
});
});
</script>

Comment: Use this to check exact position of div. I want new div to be added at the top

Answer (score 0):

Use `.append()` as it inserts elements after other elements. Or you can try `.prepend()` with animation.
[Prepend with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433939/possible-to-animate-jquery-prepend)

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=0;
$("#addBut").click(function(){

$('body').append('<div style="font-size:200%;border:1px solid black;margin-bottom:5px;"  id="first'+count+'">div '+count+'</div>');
    count++;
});
$("#delBut").click(function(){
$("#first5").remove();
});
});
</script>

Comment: Use this jquery code to check exact position of div. I want new div to be added at the top of the body

Answer (score 0):

Please try bellow code where I fixed position of the div and also set z-index to content div so it will display above the all elements

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<title>prepend demo</title>
<style>
#addBut{     //style of button which goes down
display: block; padding: 3px 10px; cursor: pointer; margin: auto;
}

.content{       //style of div which is to be prepend
position:relative;
background-color: white;
width: 500px;
height:350px;
padding: 25px;
border: 5px solid black;
 display:block;
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
z-index:99999;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position:fixed; top:2%; right:2%;">
<input type="text" id="inpText"> 
<textarea rows="12" cols="50">   //it is text area which also goes down
TextArea Location    
</textarea>
<input type="button" id="addBut" value="Add"> // HTML tag of Button which goes down
<input type="button" id="TextBut">
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var count=0;
$("#addBut").click(function(){


$('body').prepend('<div class="content"  id="first'+count+'"><h3>Heading tag</h3><p>Paragraph tag</p></div>'); 
//It is the jquery code div which I prepends
count++;

});

$( "#TextBut" )
.click(function() {
var value = $( inpText ).val();
$( "#para" ).text( value );
})
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```